# query String query Default Operator

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the query string query and default operator OR

here is my query

GET prasad/_search

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*96 prasad*"
                , "default_operator": "OR"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

I have data in my document as 96315 but this query is not hitting this document.Hits are null.When we use OR operator then it means either 96 OR prasad should in there in document (_all)?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
   {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*96* *prasad*"
                , "default_operator": "OR"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: If you still hope for an explanation, you should not post this as an answer, but amend your question.